# Как отобразить блок картинкой?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно отобразить блок картинкой, есть пустой блок, мне нужно, чтоб на сайте на его месте была картинка, помогите начинающим. Пожалуйста!

```
<div class='main_block'>
<h2>".$template_settings[txblk_1_caption]."</h2>
".$template_settings[txblk_1_text]."
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="background: url(/path/to/img.png) no-repeat 0 0; "><h2>...</h2>...</div>
```

Только нужно чтобы размеры блока были такими же, как и картинка

Comment: @Jul, спасибо можно выразить и молча, нажав "лайк" слева от ответа. "Огромное спасибо" выражается зеленой галочкой. =)

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```css
.picture {
    background: url(../img/img.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так:

```css
.main_block{
  background-image: url(../'img/img.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  max-width:100%;
}
```